# Ruby Simple Program Tracing (Yield - Method)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, yield, trace

this is a code I created based on a video course about Ruby blocks on the ruby tracks on TeamTreeHouse, here are the code and it's outputs..

My code:

```
def get_name(prompt, &block)
  print prompt + ": "
  name = gets.chomp
  print "age: "
  age = gets.chomp
  #block.call(nam,ag)
  yield name, age
  yield age
  name
end

my_name = get_name("enter your name") do |name, age|
  puts "That's a cool name, #{name}, #{age}"
end

my_name2 = get_name("enter your age") do |age|
  puts "That's a cool age, #{age}"
end

puts "my_name: #{my_name} #{my_name2}"
```

My Output:

```
treehouse:~/workspace$ ruby calling_blocks.rb                                                                             
enter your name: ahmed                                                                                                    
age: 25                                                                                                                   
That's a cool name, ahmed, 25                                                                                             
That's a cool name, 25,                                                                                                   
enter your age: 25                                                                                                        
age: 25                                                                                                                   
That's a cool age, 25                                                                                                     
That's a cool age, 25                                                                                                     
my_name: ahmed 25
```

the problem with that code is that when tracing it, I find the output irrelevant, here's what I think must be happened:

1- the first get_name block sent a prompt with question "enter your name", and then the method get_name first print the phrase "enter your name" which comes as parameter called prompt, then the method takes the name as input and takes the age as input

2- the first yield "yield name,age" send back to the first get_name block the name and age, which got received in the block through |name, age| , then they both got displayed in

```
puts "That's a cool name, #{name}, #{age}"
```

as this

```
That's a cool name, ahmed, 25
```

3- the second yield "yield age" send back to the first get_name block the age only this time, which got received in the block through |name, age|, this time since we sent back to the block only one argument, while the block has two parameters, this time the name parameter on the block received the age argument coming from "yield name", while the age parameter on the block received nothing, so in the block, the #{name} only displays value while the #{age} displays nothing

```
puts "That's a cool name, #{name}, #{age}"
```

as this

```
That's a cool name, 25,
```

is my tracing true ?
because if it's true why in the second get_name block, which is

```
my_name2 = get_name("enter your age") do |age|
  puts "That's a cool age, #{age}"
end
```

the output was:

```
That's a cool age, 25                                                                                                     
That's a cool age, 25
```

instead of:

```
That's a cool age, ahmed                                                                                                     
That's a cool age, 25
```

another question:
in

```
puts "my_name: #{my_name} #{my_name2}"
```

why the value of #{my_name2} = 25, not = ahmed, knowing that the last line in the get_name method, I returns name, not age ?

**SHORT VERSION OF THIS QUESTION:
 please trace my code for me, tell me what exactly's happening ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `get_name` method yields `name` and `adge` into block. Inside a block these variables are assigned: `name="ahmed", age=25`. The output is `That's a cool name, ahmed, 25`

2) `get_name` method yields `adge` into block. Inside a block these variables are assigned: `name=25, adge=nil`. (that is a Proc, not lambda, hence it sets `nil` to variables which were not gotten). The output is `That's a cool name, 25,`. See the comma after `25`? It actually prints `nil` too, but `nil.to_s` is empty string.

3) my_name = "ahmed" - variable is assigned

4) Since your new prompt is "enter your age" and you are entering 25, It is assigned to `name` variable in `get_name` method. Then, you enter 25 again and that value becomes assigned to `age` as well.

5) `get_name` yields two values (`name` and `age` which are now `25` and `25`) the block which takes only the first one. Then `get_name` yields one value `age` to that block.

6) `my_name_2=get_name#name=25`

Comment: thanks for your help, I really got the point and where was my error in the tracing :) , wanted to add a thumps up but I need at least 15 reps to be able to thump up someone

Comment: Was a pleasure to help you

Answer (score 0):

You only either the explicit parameter form (`&block`) or `yield`, but not both. Right now your `&block` argument is totally ignored.

If you use `&block`, you can replace the `yield(` with `block.call(`.

In either case, the call stack is not super complicated. At the point where you call `yield(` or `block.call(`, it goes into the given block (where you call `puts`) and then goes to the next line.

Another important thing to understand is that blocks don't validate the number of arguments passed to them. Someone gave a piece of advice in a StackOverflow comment (don't know the source link) which I find helpful to remember. Blocks behave like procs - they don't validate the number of arguments, and you can remember this because the words are similar. Methods behave like lamdas - they do validate the number of args.

So, when you call `yield` twice in a row, that's calling the *same block* multiple times with different arguments. You provide *two different blocks* when you invoke the function twice with different `do` sections.